# Why I am unable to use Border radius and Border collapse at the simultaneously?

Tags: html, css, border

While I am doing my HTML project I was working with tables , At that time I am unable to use Border-radius and Border-collapse at the same time in a table....

Is there any possible way to use them both in a table ....?

Comment: Can you add your code (both css and html) with a description of what you're trying to achieve? Are you looking to apply a border radius to cells, to rows or the whole table?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.